# Does Windows Azure present an IPv6 address?

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, azure

When using http://cloudflare.ipv6-test.com/validate.php to see if my website if IPv6 compliant, I see that it is not because it requires an AAAA DNS record.

My site is hosted on Azure, but I can't find an IPv6 address within the Azure Web Service (I can only see IPv4).

Does Azure support IPv6? If not, is there something else I can/should do to make my website IPv6 compliant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure only provides an IPv4 address externally. However, [Windows Azure Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432997.aspx) (software-based VPN), when creating its VPN tunnel, is IPv6-based (over the IPv4 tunnel). So, you could create a Connect group between your Windows Azure deployment (you choose which roles to add to the Connect group) and your on-prem box, and you'll have IPv6 connectivity.

Note: Across the tunnel, it's IPv6-only.